# How to Extract State info from Freeform String using Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am pulling data from Survey Monkey to get a count by State each applicant lives in but whoever created the form allowed the applicants to type their entire address in, freeform, so the state could be anywhere in the string and could be in any format ie: South Carolina, SC, S.C.  I was able to create a contains function that accomplishes this but the contains function is identifying certain parts of the string as one of the states when it really is not.  For example and address of 7999 Main St Calumet City, IL is being identified as California because the Contains function is seeing the "Ca" in Calumet and matching it with CA for California.  This is a snippet of code I'm using to get my results.  This code is basically repeated for every state.

```
{=Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Extract_State", each if
Text.Contains([#"Business Information | Business Address"],"CA") then "CA" else if
Text.Contains([#"Business Information | Business Address"],"California") then "CA" else if}
```

Comment: If you don't want  to match CA then try space CA space    There is no magic code that will extract state from the middle of freedom, especially given spelling mistakes, apartment and office numbers, etc

Comment: Agreed. You can try a bunch of prefixes and suffixes, like first search for a comma and space before, then space after, then just comma, then just space... which will hopefully match "321 S Carolina St, Nevada, IA" as Iowa (yes, there really is a city in Iowa named Nevada), but humans typed in human-named names. The best you'll get is a good guess. [Garbage in, garbage out](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Comment: As @JSmart523 implies, you can't just look for names or abbreviations, but you also have to check position information. Please add a representative data sample (as **TEXT** which can be copy/pasted), if you require more assistance.

Comment: Applying the Space between CA seemed to have solved the problem.  The data i very messy so I dont know if I will every be able to get it 100% right